# Navigate page till rendering last frame not networkidel

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm taking screenshot for large html, but i got large white space in the output image every time i try to take the image.

I made so many tests, and fount out that there're frames rendered after the `load` event, so i don't get it in the captured image.

Here's image showing the performance 
[image]
The red line showing the `load` event and there's frames after that line.

I tried to read all the documentation for the package but i'm a civil engineer and don't know lots in programming, i tried my best and couldn't find a solution for it.

There's 4 options in `page.goto` and they don't solve the problem, here's the url for the documentation .
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options

Here's my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('D:\Image_2.HTML', {waitUntil: 'load'});
  function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
console.log(page.frames())
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png',fullPage : true});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it using another packages, the problem was in writing the image not the rendering . so i split the big image for 4 quarters.

```
/* Dependencies */
const chromeLauncher = require('lighthouse/chrome-launcher/chrome-launcher');
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
const fs = require('fs');

/** ARGUMENTS AND CONFIGUIRATION
 * expects arguments to be
 * -w int (width)
 * -h int (height)
 * -p int (port)
 * --url string (url)
 */

const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const windowWidth = argv.w ? argv.w : 1024;
const windowHeight = argv.h ? argv.h : 1024;
const filename = argv.filename;
const filename2 = argv.filename2;
const filename3 = argv.filename3;
const filename4 = argv.filename4;

headless=true
const launchConfig = {
    chromeFlags: [
        `--window-size=${windowWidth},${windowHeight}`,
        '--disable-gpu',
     headless ? '--headless' : ''
     ]
}
//function sleep(ms) {
 // return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
//}


function saveScreenshot(imageData, pageURL) {
    fs.writeFile(
        filename,
        imageData.data, {encoding:'base64'},
        (err)=>{
            console.warn('error', "1");
        }
    );

}
function saveScreenshot2(imageData, pageURL) {
    fs.writeFile(
        filename2,
        imageData.data, {encoding:'base64'},
        (err)=>{
            console.warn('error', "2");
        }
    );

}
function saveScreenshot3(imageData, pageURL) {
    fs.writeFile(
        filename3,
        imageData.data, {encoding:'base64'},
        (err)=>{
            console.warn('error', "3");
        }
    );

}
function saveScreenshot4(imageData, pageURL) {
    fs.writeFile(
        filename4,
        imageData.data, {encoding:'base64'},
        (err)=>{
            console.warn('error', "4");
        }
    );

}

async function launchChrome(headless = true) {
  return await chromeLauncher.launch(launchConfig);
}

 async function saveScreenShotFromURL(pageURL) {
     const chrome = await launchChrome();
     const protocol = await CDP({port: chrome.port});
     const {Page, Runtime} = protocol;

     await Promise.all([Page.enable(), Runtime.enable()]);

     Page.navigate({url: pageURL});
     Page.loadEventFired(async () => {

     const screenshot = await Page.captureScreenshot({clip : {x:0,y:0,width : 3100,height : 3030,scale : 1}});
     const screenshot2 =await  Page.captureScreenshot({clip : {x:0,y:3030,width : 3100,height : 3030,scale : 1}});
     const screenshot3 =await  Page.captureScreenshot({clip : {x:3100,y:0,width : 3100,height : 3030,scale : 1}});
     const screenshot4 = await Page.captureScreenshot({clip : {x:3100,y:3030,width : 3100,height : 3030,scale : 1}});

        Promise.resolve( screenshot).then((imageData)=>{
            saveScreenshot(imageData,pageURL);
        });
        Promise.resolve( screenshot2).then((imageData)=>{
            saveScreenshot2(imageData,pageURL);
        });
        Promise.resolve( screenshot3).then((imageData)=>{
            saveScreenshot3(imageData,pageURL);
        });
        Promise.resolve( screenshot4).then((imageData)=>{
            saveScreenshot4(imageData,pageURL);
        });

        protocol.close();
        chrome.kill();
     });
 }
```

saveScreenShotFromURL(argv.url)
Please if you know how to `async` the 4 images to print at the same time, please help me.

Comment: why a fixed number 4?

Comment: Sorry for replying late, do you mean why i split large images to 4 small images?, you can change it to many many small images, 4 was an  assumption .

Answer (score 0):

The script you posted defines the `sleep` function, but doesn't call it.
And if you wait for enough time, you'll get the page to the desired state.

> NOTE: you can "sleep" with `await page.waitFor()` method.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('D:\Image_2.HTML', {waitUntil: 'load'});
  // wait for 2 seconds
  await page.waitFor(2000); 
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png',fullPage : true});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

In general, there's no good answer to the "when my page is loaded" question. The `waitUntil` options available in the `page.goto` are just common heuristics, they might fail in multiple cases.

It's hard to say what went wrong in your case; usually one would need to understand the web page inner working to figure its desired loaded state.

Comment: Thanks alot for replying, sleep wasn't solving the problem and waitfor too, Wanna me upload the file to you and send link for it through chat ?

Comment: The html render perfectly, but the problem is, there're frames render after load event, so when i capture screen, the un rendered frames get written as whitespace.

Comment: what i'm thinking in, if there's away to take screenshot after rendering image in the html, because my html is a map and consist of lots of images composite with each other

Comment: when waitUntil:'load' then write waitfor after it , it do nothing because page stopped rendering after load event, if there's something like WaitUntil : 'FinishRendering' , and rendering always finish after load event .

Comment: how big is your html? We have a bunch of rasterizations issues currently with huge images, e.g. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/959

Comment: Please check my html
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A6M7zcipODtzQVtlm2NPOrNaxi3JABnS

Comment: @OmarAbdEl-Naser ah i see now. Unfortunately it's the image rasterization bug. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/477

Comment: So, the only solution is to reduce the image width or height to get the full image right ?

Comment: You're right. Smaller image sizes should render without issues.